# Hello World Custom Rest Api endpoint not working

Tags: apex, rest-api, oauth2

Salesforce provides [a example](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm) of how to define a custom rest endpoint and how to make calls to that endpoint. It is not working for me. Why? I have successfully retrieved an OAuth token that I have successfully used with the REST Api.

Here is the Rest class in apex:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Account/*')
global with sharing class MyRestResource {

@HttpDelete
global static void doDelete() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    Account account = [SELECT Id FROM Account ];
    delete account;
}

@HttpGet
global static Account doGet() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    Account result = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website FROM Account];
    return result;
}

@HttpPost
global static String doPost(String name,
    String phone, String website) {
    Account account = new Account();
    account.Name = name;
    account.phone = phone;
    account.website = website;
    insert account;
    return account.Id;
}
}
```

and here is some python code that I am using to make the get request:

```
import requests

url = 'https://na15.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account/001i000000VdaoqAAB'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer 00Di0000000iQ.....'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 
print r.text
```

I am getting the following error:

> [{"message":"Could not find a match for URL /Account/001i000000VdaoqAAB","errorCode":"NOT_FOUND"}]

Is there some setting that I need to enable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure on that error but I do see a couple of potential issues that might be causing you problems

The get is setup wrongly - when I tried that, I got an error because it is not filtering by the Id you pass in - see line highlighted below from docs that you are missing. As such, it needs to returns a list of records (the code does work when you change the return type)

```
@HttpGet
    global static Account doGet() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        **String accountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);**
        Account result = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
        return result;
    }
```

Also, I probably wouldn't name the RestResource 'Account' as that is a standard resource name...wondering if that is causing a conflict?

**Update**: If you have a namespace enabled for your org, then it will need to be included in the url. In your case it would be:

https://na15.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/**your_namespace**/Account/001i000000VdaoqAAB
where "your_namespace" is the [namespace of your org](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=register_namespace_prefix.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I am getting a 404 and not a 500. I would assume that the error you found in my code would cause a 500 error. I've also tried changing the url mapping to /helloworld and that doesn't work either. When you ran my code did you get a 500 or 404?

Comment: I actually got an Apex error returned because the get returned more than one record - so the call itself worked fine.

Comment: Also the 'Account' url mapping was provided in the official salesforce documentation, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why you are able to hit that endpoint, and I am not. I am currently using a Development org. I would assume that shouldn't be causing any problems.

Comment: just to confirm - does this org have a namespace enabled? If so, you need to add that to the URL...

Comment: That was it! I didn't realize that I needed to add that to the url!
(thank you. I need to bask in this moment and let the last 24 hours of frustration wash away.)

Comment: https://<instance name> .salesforce.com/services/apexrest/<namespace>/hello

Answer (score 0):

See if this blog post helps out: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2012/02/28/apex-rest-service-not-found/

Comment: That might be it. I just refactored one of the core classes of my app, and I haven't fixed the unit tests yet. They don't run or compile at the moment. I will let you know if that fixed it once I fix the compilation errors and run the tests.

Comment: I've fixed all of my unit tests and ran them all, but I am still getting the 404 not found error. Do I have to create a unit test for the controller/endpoint as well?